# getting images from iPhone simulator

Tags: ios, iphone

I have just created an image and saved it in iPhone simulator phone library. I want to view this image(not from Photo Library) to view its properties from document resources. But I am not able to access the contents of photo library.

Thanks
Pankaj

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Go to this folder (Finder, Shift+Command+G):

`~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/(version)/Media/DCIM/100APPLE`

replacing "(version)" with your Simulator version. You should find all the photos there.

Comment: This folder no longer existed in version 7.0+

Answer (score 88):

With Xcode 6 the simulator image files are now located in:

```
~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/<device UDID>/data/Media/DCIM/100APPLE
```

Where the value of `<device UDID>` can be determined using the command: `xcrun simctl list devices`.

EDIT - Path is still valid for Xcode 10.1 version.

Comment: You can also get the `<device UDID>` from **Devices** window (Shift+CMD+2)

Comment: `xcrun simctl list devices | grep Booted | grep -E  '\w+-\w+-\w+-\w+-\w+' -o` to reduce noise

Answer (score -1):

In newer versions of the Simulator, there is a button which will let you take a screenshot (the camera icon in the picture below):

[image: Simulator Screenshot Tool]

The new screenshot will show up next to Simulator window and you can drag it to your desktop to save the file:

[image: Simulator Screenshot Taken]