# How to hide iOS simulator Tool Bar?

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

Seems like the iOS simulator added a new ToolBar, which I am unable to hide.

[image]

Is there any shortcut to hide it?

Answer (score 30):

Assuming you want a nice screenshot with the device the following worked for me, from Swany's answer on [this Apple forum thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/131139) :

In a terminal, disable shadows on Screenshots with the following command:

```
defaults write com.apple.screencapture disable-shadow -bool TRUE; killall SystemUIServer
```

Take a screenshot with Screencapture, either by selecting a region without the Toolbar, or of the whole Simulator window and crop the Toolbar.

You can still add shadow on the image wherever you use it.

The following command reverses the change to the screencapture app :

```
defaults write com.apple.screencapture disable-shadow -bool FALSE; killall SystemUIServer
```

Comment: This answer is amazing. I didn't even know I needed this!!

Comment: You can just run these commands, and do ⌘ + shift + 4 + Spacebar on the simulator running your App and there you have it - screen capture with bazel.

Comment: You don't need to execute this command.

1. Just engage the screen capture with ⌘ + shift + 4 + Spacebar 
2. Hold option when you click to do the screenshot. There will be no shadow

Answer (score 20):

While you won't be able to hide the toolbar, I discovered a solution that worked very well for me and doesn't involve changing user defaults (which didn't work for me).

With the Simulator window open, open up the Screenshot application. On the floating utility bar, there will be an option for "Capture Selected Window".

Click on this, and it will turn your mouse cursor into a camera. Hover over the widow you want to take a screenshot of (Simulator in this case) and alt + click.

This will save a screenshot with no drop shadow, which you can easily crop in Preview or any other imaging editing software in order to remove the bar at the top.

It will have a transparent background so it will be very easy to work with.

Comment: In the simulator, select Device, Trigger Screenshot to get a screenshot. This puts it in the Photos app of the simulator. To get it out of there, follow [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488915/getting-images-from-iphone-simulator).

Answer (score 9):

No there is no way to hide the toolbar. It is an integrated toolbar and title bar.

If you'd like to see this option please file a feedback request for it.