# iOS Simulator: remove control bar at the top of the device

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

Is it possible to remove the control bar at the top of the iOS Simulator (highlighted in the red frame on the screenshot)?
I'm using Xcode 13 Release.

[image]

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60889509/how-to-hide-ios-simulator-tool-bar

Comment: I don't think there's a way to remove it, but try turning off Window -> Show Device Bezels — gets rid of the space between the bar and the device.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried removing the bezels, that didn't help.

Comment: Unfortunately, the linked solution also doesn't help as my goal is to declutter the UI to show in the video, rather than the screenshot.